# Nested namespace can't be found in spite of including header file

Tags: c++, namespaces, cinder

I have two projects, one is a sample (which *compiles without error*) and looks like this (first few lines shown only):

### Working Example

```
#include "cinder/app/App.h"
#include "cinder/app/RendererGl.h"
#include "cinder/Surface.h"
#include "cinder/gl/gl.h"
#include "cinder/gl/Texture.h"
#include "cinder/Rand.h"
#include "cinder/qtime/QuickTimeGl.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

class QTimeAdvApp : public App {
  public:
    void prepareSettings( Settings *settings );
    void setup();

    void keyDown( KeyEvent event );
    void fileDrop( FileDropEvent event );

    void update();
    void draw();

    void addActiveMovie( qtime::MovieGlRef movie );
    void loadMovieUrl( const std::string &urlString );
    void loadMovieFile( const fs::path &path );

};
```

Note especially the line: `void addActiveMovie( qtime::MovieGlRef movie );`

The other project, which needs to make use of the same library (Quicktime OpenGL within LibCinder), tries to do something similar - one again an extract:

### Use in Project

```
#pragma once

#include "AbstractContent.h"
#include "cinder/gl/Texture.h"
#include "cinder/Tween.h"
#include "AbstractTransition.h"
#include "cinder/qtime/QuickTimeGl.h"

namespace TH {

    class VideoContent : public AbstractContent {
    public:
        VideoContent();
        ~VideoContent();
        virtual void setup();
        void loadMovie(ci::Url url);
        void loadLocalMovie(ci::fs::path path);
        void setPreloadedMovie(ci::qtime::MovieGlRef movie);
```

This one throws a compiler error: **No member named 'qtime' in namespace 'cinder'**

Notice again the virtually identical line: `void setPreloadedMovie(ci::qtime::MovieGlRef movie);` In fact, you can use the full qualified name `ci:qtime:MovieGlRef` in the first example and it compiles just fine (as expected).

What on earth is going on here? Why does the "Use in Project" version throw a compiler error: **No member named 'qtime' in namespace 'cinder'**?

Just for clarity, the QuickTimeGl.h file in turn includes another file which definitely declares the namespace and the type def:

```
namespace cinder { namespace qtime {

typedef std::shared_ptr<class MovieGl>  MovieGlRef;
```

Am I missing something? I'm pretty sure I'm including the correct header file, as before, and even trying to use the fully qualified namespace but still the compiler doesn't find the definition?

Comment: Get rid of the globaly scoped using directives in the header. May not solve your problem, but will make the code less polluting.

Comment: Is the outer namespace named `ci` or `cinder`?

Comment: @StoryTeller The using directives are NOT being used in my code (the second chunk). They are only being used in the working sample code.

Comment: Are you sure `qtime::MovieGlRef` is in `ci` and not `ci::app`?  With those using statements in the first example it could be either.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: they are aliases for one another, as far as I can tell. So in the first example, substituting ```cinder::qtime::MovieGlRef``` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referencing the global namespace, with `::ci::qtime` rather than simply `ci::qtime`? This should not make a difference, but sometimes C++ compilers trip over these kind of things.